# Page_ClientValidate is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I Write a js function In MaterPage

```
 function CheckClientValidate(Validations) {
        Page_ClientValidate(Validations);
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and i use the MaterPage in my webProject,amost the Page in the Project can use the func
but one get error like `Page_ClientValidate is not defined`
i can use the FireBug to find the func `Page_ClientValidate` but why show the error only the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your are not using master page on that particular page.

Comment: i got it , there i forget to write the Validator Control XD